# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models' in Python

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I try running my test file and I get this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\HP\projects\exercises\airbnb_clone\AirBnB_clone\tests\test_models\test_base_model.py", line 4, in <module>
    from models.base_model import BaseModel
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'
```

Here is the first few lines of the test file:

```py
""" TestBaseModel module for testing the BaseModel class"""
import unittest
from models.base_model import BaseModel
import uuid
import os
import datetime


class TestBaseModel(unittest.TestCase):
    """ Tests for the BaseModel class """

    def test_id(self):
        """ test id """
        base1 = BaseModel()
        base2 = BaseModel()
        self.assertNotEqual(base1.id, base2.id)`
```

I tried adding he models path to `PYTHONPATH` and it didn't work

Comment: How would we know where `models` module comes from? Is this a folder on your filesystem?

Comment: Make sure that the models directory contains a file name `__init__.py`. This file will make the models dir into a package.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it. All I had to do was run the test files in the root directory instead of the sub folder where they were originally contained. I'll be leaving this here incase anyone has the same issue.